# how to clear grow heap size in titanium app in android?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have download 100 images store in application data directory its working fine
but i have download more images then grow heap size problem is coming and application is closed.I have remove all objects,value of objects define null and window is also closed but result is same.

ERROR:grow heap (frag case) to 14.687MB for 517197-byte allocation

Like in Core android System.gc();
So what is the option of titanium

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 2):

why not use
[android:largeHeap="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap)

```
  <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<manifest>
    <application android:largeHeap="true"/>
</manifest>
```

read titanium official doc [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-RequestingalargeheapfromDalvik)

Comment: This is one of the tags that I was thinking of when mentioning it in my answers. As I said there it doesn't do much good in my experience.

Comment: I found this tag helpful, in native as well as titanium

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have no control over the garbage collection. The JavaScript interpreter does this for you.

I did something similar in a project (downloading lots of images) and also ran into memory issues. The most optimal solution I have found is to make sure that garbage collection is possible. The reason for this is that the JavaScript interpreter executes your code and if you loop through all the images and download them, it might not get to do garbage collection before you're done downloading. This means that all the temporary images will still be in memory.

To deal with this issue, you either need to use the `defer`-method of [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or the `setTimeout`-function. In sense what they both do is that they tell the interpreter that it's okay to run other stuff before this e.g. garbage collection.

This code sample (using underscore.js) should give you the general idea:

```
var images = [...many entries here...]; 

function downloadImage(index) {
  //Make sure the index is valid
  if(index < images.length) {
    var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHttpClient({
       onload: function() {
         //Save the image to the filesystem.
         _defer.(downloadImage, ++index); //Download the next image.
       }
    });

    //Run the HttpClient here.
  }
}

_.defer(downloadImage, 0); //Start the download sequence.
```

There are also some tags that you can set in the tiapp.xml file, but in my experience they don't help much.

---

These three articles on "Keeping your app response" explain the point I'm trying to make quite well:

1. [Part 1: The problem](http://www.tidev.io/2014/02/17/keeping-your-app-responsive-part-1/)
2. [Part 2: The reason](http://www.tidev.io/2014/02/27/keeping-your-app-responsive-part-2/)
3. [Part 3: The solution](http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/24/keeping-your-app-responsive-part-3/)